# Quill: how to get deleted content?

Tags: quill

From Quill documentation i got that quill's Delta delete operation return only length of deleted content ([doc](https://github.com/quilljs/delta#delete)). But i'm need to analyze this content.
What is best way to get deleted content, like new content in [insert operation](https://github.com/quilljs/delta#insert)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot get it from an isolated Delta. However from Quill's [`text-change`](http://quilljs.com/docs/api/#text-change) event the second parameter is the previous contents and you can use [diff](https://github.com/quilljs/delta#diff) to find the difference.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it's does't work.
I try it in [this code](http://codepen.io/szobov/pen/PmdvZO) but, if you type any symbols, you see error in browser console: `Uncaught Error: diff() called with non-document`.
May be i use it wrong or may be it's not usefull for my case, because (in code from [Delta](https://github.com/quilljs/delta/blob/master/lib/delta.js#L192-L197)) this method throw error if it diffing delta without insert command, like `retain` operation.

Comment: You need to diff the previous contents with the current contents. You are diffing the previous content with another diff at the moment.

Comment: Unfortunately, i've already tried it. I updated this [codepaste](http://codepen.io/szobov/pen/PmdvZO) and you can see error. I think that it's happen because in this [code](https://github.com/quilljs/delta/blob/master/lib/delta.js#L191) we apply this [function](https://github.com/quilljs/delta/blob/master/lib/delta.js#L193-L197) on both deltas. Old or new, no matter. If one of this delta has another operation instead of `insert` we throw error.

Comment: No you are still diffing a diff with state which makes no sense. http://codepen.io/quill/pen/pPxBPr is what I am suggesting. You can see the delta passed in is the same as if you diff the new with old, but you want the other direction, so you can just diff old with new.

Comment: Exactly! It's what i need. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can set a keybinding on the delete button and you will have an access to the data with the range.index etc. After you can use return true if you want to delete norma